# Notepad ++ replace random numbers inside a same word

Tags: notepad++

how can i replace in notepad ++

all those lines

```
myPlay1()
myPlay2()
myPlay3()
myPlay4()
myPlay5()
myPlay6()
myPlay7()
myPlay8()
myPlay9()
myPlay10()
```

to this

```
myPlayC(this)
```

so i think need to be something like    FIND: myPlay*()  and REPLACE:  myPlayC(this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing the Search Mode to **Regular Expression**.

Then find

```
myPlay[0-9]*\(\)
```

Replace with

```
myPlayC\(this\)
```